# VB - Read file line by line check existence

Tags: vb.net, file, line, exists

i have the following text file containing paths of files that i need to check the existence of :

```
C:\path\to\file1
C:\path\to\file2
C:\path\to\file3
C:\path\to\file4
```

I ve tried to write some vb (for the first time) to read over said text file, line by line, store the line, and check for existence of that string. Here's the code :

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()
' Store the line in this String.
Dim line As String

' Create new StreamReader instance with Using block.
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
    ' Read one line from file
    line = reader.ReadLine
End Using

' Write if the file exists or not
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(line) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
End Sub
```

My question is this, say that i wanted to add a remote path to the file, what would i need to change in the above code to be able to check that?

ie

```
C:\path\to\file1
C:\path\to\file2
C:\path\to\file3
C:\path\to\file4
\\server.domain\path\to\file5
\\server.domain2\path\to\file6
```

Thank you in advance.

Correction after comment :

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
Sub Main()
' Loop over lines in file.
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    ' Display the line.
    Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(line) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Side-Note: currently you're checking only the first line of the file. You can also use the simple `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`. Apart from that it should work also with UNC paths

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network paths usually are like this:
//192.168.x.y/Users/

after Users, you put the path of the file.

192.168.x.y is the IP address of the remote machine. You can use the hostname too in place of the IP address.

I hope this helps.